# Retrieve azure update management status using REST API

Tags: azure, rest

I'm having trouble with **retrieving azure update management details programmatically**. I couldn't find any REST API or CLI method to get the data from update management view. There were only powershell scripts.

These are the details I want to retrieve via REST API

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- As shown in below screenshot, currently I see only below highlighted REST API's that are related to update management. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/) is the document reference for the same.

[image]

- If these REST API's doesn't help to accomplish your requirement then if interested you may share it as feature request in this [uservoice or feedback forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/905242-update-management).
  In general, Azure feature team would check feasibility of a feature request, prioritize against existing feature backlog, add in roadmap as appropriate and would announce and/or update the related Azure document once a feature request is addressed.
- On the other hand, with the help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/update-management/query-logs) references, you may find the same information in update management related kusto tables which you can query with the help of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/dataaccess/query) REST API.
- Here is the reference link for the same issue which was addressed  in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/475393/azure-update-management-data-retrieve-via-rest-api.html)