# is there any rest api url for get all virtual machine compliance status?

Tags: python, azure, azure-automation, azure-vm, azure-management-api

*I am using this [api url](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/%7BvmName%7D/assessPatches?api-version=2022-08-01) for getting virtual machine compliance status, however its giving me 202 Accepted response.*

*I have attached image for reference, I wanted to get these information through api.*

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application named **`WebApp`** and granted **API permission** like below:

[image]

I generated **access token** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id: appID
grant_type: client_credentials
client_secret: secret
scope: https://management.azure.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

Using above token, I too got ***same response*** like `202 Accepted` while running the ***same query*** as you like below:

```http
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/{vmName}/assessPatches?api-version=2022-08-01
```

**Response:**

[image]

Currently, there is **no** such `REST API` query that can fetch you all virtual machine's compliance status. To confirm that, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366457/retrieve-azure-update-management-status-using-rest-api).
*Alternatively*, you can make use of **Kusto query**.

I have below information on virtual machine's **compliance status** in my automation account:

[image]

To get this **information** from Kusto query, you need to follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Automation Accounts -> Select account -> Logs -> Azure Update Management -> Computers list -> Run***

[image]

When I ran the query with **scope** as subscription, I got the **results** successfully like below:

[image]

**Reference:**

[Retrieve azure update management status using REST API by VenkateshDodda-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366457/retrieve-azure-update-management-status-using-rest-api)